# Limit of functions and improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

As a criterion for the existence of the limit of a function we have:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists *iff* for **each** sequence $(a_n)$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=a$ the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(a_n)$ exists.

Let's consider an improper integral $\int\limits_a^{b}f(t)dt$ where $a<b$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$.

The improper integral exists *iff* $f(t)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,\beta]$ for each $\beta$ with $a<\beta<b$ and the limit $\lim\limits_{\beta\to b} \int\limits_a^{\beta}f(t)dt$ exists. In fact, $\lim\limits_{\beta\to b} \int\limits_a^{\beta}f(t)dt$ can be interpreted as a limit of a function, let's call it $F(\beta):=\int\limits_a^{\beta}f(t)$. Hence, it must be possible to prove the existence of $\lim\limits_{\beta\to b}F(\beta)$ by the above criterion. However, in our lecture it says that in the context of improper integrals it is sufficient to find only **one** sequence such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} F(\beta_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int\limits_a^{\beta_n}f(t)dt$ exists.

---

Why is it sufficient to show it only for one sequence?

Comment: Maybe you're working under the hypothesis $f\ge0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. No, there are no restrictions imposed on $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $f(x) = \cos x$, $a = 0$, $b = \infty$, and $\beta_n = n\pi$.

We have $\beta_n \to \infty$, and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^{\beta_n}f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{n\pi} \cos x\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sin n\pi - \sin 0) = 0$$

However, the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \cos x \, dx$ does not converge, since $\underset{\beta \to \infty}\lim \sin \beta$ does not exist.

---

If $f \geqslant 0$, then $F(\beta)$ is nonnegative and nondecreasing. Suppose there exists a sequence $\beta_n$ where $\beta_n \to \infty$ and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F(\beta_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^{\beta_n} f(x) \, dx = I$$

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $|F(\beta_n) - I| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geqslant N$. If $\beta > \beta_N$, then since $\beta_n \to \infty$, there exists $m > N$ such that  $F(\beta_N) \leqslant F(\beta) \leqslant F(\beta_m),$ and

$$-\epsilon < F(\beta_N) - I < F(\beta)-I < F(\beta_m)- I < \epsilon$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{\beta \to \infty} F(\beta) = \lim_{\beta \to \infty}\int_a^{\beta} f(x) \, dx = I$$

Comment: Ah ok, then there is a mistake in the lecture notes. There should be imposed an additional property on $f$, e.g. $f\geq 0$ as @Gae. S pointed out. Right?

Comment: Yes - correct. I added a proof that convergence for one sequence suffices when $f \geqslant 0$.

Comment: It feels like that it is necessary that the sequence $(\beta_n)$ must go to $\infty$. Why is that so? Why is it not possible that $b\in\mathbb{R}$? Or is it?

Comment: It works if $\beta_n \to b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Just modify the proof slightly.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. What if $\beta_n:=b+\frac{1}{n}$ then we don't even know if $F(\beta_n)$ exists. Whereas everything could be o.k. if we consider $\beta_n:=b-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: By definition $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ is the limit from the left, that is $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{\beta \to b-}\int_a^\beta f(x) \, dx$ along with the obvious requirement that $f$ is R-integrable on $[a,\beta]$ for all $a < \beta < b$.  How do you define it as $\lim_{\beta \to b+} \int_a^\beta f(x) \, dx$ where the interval $[a,\beta]$ includes $b$ where there is a singularity?

Comment: So please consider only $\beta_n = b - 1/n$ where everything could be OK as you say.

Comment: ... and for the proof show that if $\beta_N < \beta < b$, then there must exist $m > N$ such that $\beta_N < \beta < \beta_m < b$.  Now choose $N$ such that  for all $n \geqslant N$ we have $I- \epsilon < F(\beta_n) < I + \epsilon$ with $F(\beta)$ squeezed in between $F(\beta_N)$ and $F(\beta_m)$.